# Are the tools to rip a DVD different from the tools for ripping a VCD?

Tags: ripping, virtualdub, vcd

What are your suggested tools to rip a VCD? There might be multiple discs, and I don't want to lose too much quality and detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VCDs are mpeg formats.  You can technically just drag and drop the files and play them. To merge them, you can use virtualdub or avidemux, which is newer.

http://www.avidemux.org/

Comment: you mean i can merge AVSEQ.dat files together?